# Can Expresso Store limit the total order weight

Tags: expresso-store

I have set up my Expresso Store shipping method to calculate:

- Maximum Order Weight  100g / Base Rate 500 yen
- Maximum Order Weight  200g / Base Rate 600 yen

... up to 2000g

I am wondering if there is a way to limit the total order weight to 2000g?

Answer (score 0):

Store doesn't have a variable to get the total weight for an order otherwise you could use that, something like:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
    {if my_total_weight <= 2000}
      <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
    {if:else
       Order weight must be 2000 or less
    {/if}
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

My initial though is to use a maths plugin to total up the order weight then use that to show/hide the checkout button accordingly. https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tally might work for you using something like my example above.